# Hook: can call string::size() but crashing when reading string data... how to read without crash?

Tags: c++, function-hooking, strings

I'm hooking a function that reads and decrypt files and my idea is to read the buffer once it's decrypted:

```
typedef void(__thiscall* _readFileContents)(DWORD* _resourceManager, std::string* buffer, std::string& fileName, bool safe);
_readFileContents original_readFileContents;
DWORD gateway_readFileContents;

void __fastcall readFileContents_hook(DWORD* _resourceManager, void* /*ecx*/, std::string* buffer, std::string& fileName, bool safe) {
    std::cout << "[" << safe << "] readFileContents_hook: " << fileName << std::endl;
    
    ((_readFileContents)gateway_readFileContents)(_resourceManager, buffer, fileName, safe);

    std::string combinedContent;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buffer->size(); ++i) {
        combinedContent.push_back(buffer->at(i));
    }

    return ((_readFileContents)gateway_readFileContents)(_resourceManager, buffer, fileName, safe); // same results with return; only
}

original_readFileContents = (_readFileContents)(moduleBase + 0x12345);
gateway_readFileContents = (DWORD)TrampHook32((char*)original_readFileContents, (char*)readFileContents_hook, 6);
```

The problem, is that whenever I touch the **buffer** variable, I get a wonderful crash :)

But, I've found an exception! I can get the size() without issues:

```
std::cout << "Buffer size with size(): " << buffer->size() << std::endl;
```

[image]

So, how can I read the data without crashing?

PS: This is the original code (it's open source and I'm using it for learning purposes):

```
std::string ResourceManager::readFileContents(const std::string& fileName, bool safe)
{
    std::string fullPath = resolvePath(fileName);
    
    if (fullPath.find("/downloads") != std::string::npos) {
        auto dfile = g_http.getFile(fullPath.substr(10));
        if (dfile)
            return std::string(dfile->response.begin(), dfile->response.end());
    }

    PHYSFS_File* file = PHYSFS_openRead(fullPath.c_str());
    if(!file)
        stdext::throw_exception(stdext::format("unable to open file '%s': %s", fullPath, PHYSFS_getErrorByCode(PHYSFS_getLastErrorCode())));

    int fileSize = PHYSFS_fileLength(file);
    std::string buffer(fileSize, 0);
    PHYSFS_readBytes(file, (void*)&buffer[0], fileSize);
    PHYSFS_close(file);

    if (safe) {
        return buffer;
    }

    // skip decryption for bot configs
    if (fullPath.find("/bot/") != std::string::npos) {
        return buffer;
    }

    static std::string unencryptedExtensions[] = { ".otml", ".otmm", ".dmp", ".log", ".txt", ".dll", ".exe", ".zip" };

    if (!decryptBuffer(buffer)) {
        bool ignore = (m_customEncryption == 0);
        for (auto& it : unencryptedExtensions) {
            if (fileName.find(it) == fileName.size() - it.size()) {
                ignore = true;
            }
        }
        if(!ignore)
            g_logger.fatal(stdext::format("unable to decrypt file: %s", fullPath));
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by changing the signature:**

```
typedef std::string*(__thiscall* _readFileContents)(DWORD* _resourceManager, std::string* buffer, std::string& fileName, bool safe);
```